# How can I import ngModule from node_modules source code?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to import one project ngModule from another project (lerna/yarn workspace). Submodule is located under `../../node_modules/@web/views`. When I run ng serve I get an error which is saying:

> 'Error: /web/node_modules/@web/views/src/app/views/views.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.`

How can I properly make angular transpile that files too?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the ngModule under node_module and paste it in your `src/app` folder. It will now compile with `ng serve` command.

Let me know if this worked for you.